# Why does php code not recognize a database update?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have some php and html code and a small bit of JavaScript. Its a like system. Click the like button or dislike button and when you exit/leave the page the JavaScript and ajax runs a php file to update the database with the changes.(+1 to likes or +1 to dislikes or -1 to dislikes etc.) There is one problem. I click like/dislike and then i leave/ refresh page and the likes have not changed in value. If i dont click anything, which means im not updating the database and i refresh/leave a second time the likes are updated on the screen to what they should be. The database gets updated when its suppose to, its the code that dosnt use the new value for whatever reason. Here's my code:

```
 <?php
session_start();
error_reporting(0);

    $GOTID = $_GET['id'];
    $GOTtitle = $_GET['title'];

     include_once "mysql_connect.php";
     include_once "like.php";
     //include_once "dislike.php";
      $email ='';

      $log = null;
        $log1 = null;
        if(isset($_SESSION["ID"])){
          $log1 = $_SESSION["ID"];
        }else{
          $log1=null;
        }

    if(isset($_SESSION["EMAIL"])){
      $log = $_SESSION["EMAIL"];
      $email = $_SESSION["EMAIL"];
     // echo $email;
    }else{
      $log=null;
    }
    $_SESSION["EMAIL"] = $log;

     $title = "";
     $text="";
     $tags = "";
     $views = "";
     $likes = "";
     $dislikes = "";
     $id = "";
     $userid = "";
     $date = "";
     $thumbnail = "";
     $imageext = "";
     $texttype = "";



     $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM videos WHERE id=$GOTID");

     while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($data)) {
         $title = $row[0];
         $descrip = $row[1];
         $id = $row[2];
         $userid = $row[3];
         $date = $row[4];
         $views = $row[5];
         $likes = $row[6];
         $dislikes = $row[7];
         $thumbnail = $row[8];
         $imagext = $row[10];
         $videourl = $row[11];
      }   

      if($likes != '0' || $dislikes !='0'){
      $total = $likes + $dislikes;
      $likebar = round(($likes / $total) * 100);
      $finlikes = (($likebar * 150)/100);
      }else{
        $finlikes = 150;
      }

          $query5 = mysql_query("UPDATE `videos` SET `views` = `views`+1 WHERE `videos`.`id` = $GOTID;");
          $stop = false;

          $fetchlast = mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM videos WHERE id=(SELECT MAX(id) FROM videos)");
          $lastrow = mysql_fetch_row($fetchlast);
          $lastid = $lastrow[0];

          for ($i=1; $i <= $lastid; $i++) { 
            if($GOTID == $id){
              $stop = true;

              break;
            }else{
              if($i >=$lastid && $GOTID != $id){
                $stop = false;
                 header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
                 $_GET['e'] = 404;
                 die();
                 exit;
              }
            }

          }

     $username = '';
     $userrep = '';
     $rank = '';
     $imageData = '';

     $currentname = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM allaccounts WHERE id=$userid");

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($currentname)) {
          $username = $row[0];
          $rank = $row[3];
          $userrep = $row[7];
          $data = $row["image"];
          $ext = $row["filetype"];

       //   $img1 = Img_Resize($data);
         // $imageData = mysql_real_escape_string(file_get_contents($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]));
        }


     $liked = false;
     $disliked = false;
     $done = false;


     $thing = mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM likes WHERE id=(SELECT MAX(id) FROM likes)");
     $lastrow = mysql_fetch_row($thing);
     $lastid = $lastrow[0];

     if($lastid == null || $lastid == '0'){
       $lastid = '1';
     }   

     $state1 = '';

     for ($i=1; $i <= $lastid+1; $i++) { 
        $current = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM likes WHERE id=$i");
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($current)) {
           $id1 = $row[0];
           $userid1 = $row[1];
           $state1 = $row[2];
           $articleid1 = $row[3];
       if($done == false){
         if($email == $userid1 && $articleid1 == $id && $state1 == '1'){
          $liked = true;
          $disliked = false;
          $done = true;
          break;
         }else{
          $liked = false;
         }
         if($email == $userid1 && $articleid1 == $id && $state1 == '0'){
          $disliked = false;
          $liked = false;
          $done = true;
          break;
         }
         if($email == $userid1 && $articleid1 == $id && $state1 == '2'){
          $disliked = true;
          $liked = false;
          $done = true;
          break;
         }else{
          $disliked = false;
         }
       }
      }


     }
     $donetitle = str_replace(" ", "-", $title);
     $_SESSION["prevpage"] = "video/".$id."/".$donetitle."";

     $lik = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM videos WHERE id=$GOTID");
      while ($row22 = mysql_fetch_array($lik)) {
                            $Olikes = $row22[6];
      }
     $dis = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM videos WHERE id=$GOTID");
      while ($row22 = mysql_fetch_array($dis)) {
                            $Odislikes = $row22[7];
      } 
?>
<html>
<head>
   <title><?php echo $title;?></title>
   <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <script type="text/javascript">
      var likes = <?php echo $likes;?>;
      var dislikes = <?php echo $dislikes;?>;

  </script>
<div class = "container_24">
   <header>
    </header>

   <div class = "main clearfix">
    <div class ="grid_24 ">
      <div id = "rectarticletop">
             <a  onclick='like()' id="likebtn"><img  id="alike"src="img/icons/like.png" alt = "like"/></a> 
             <div id="dislikes"><div style="width:<?php echo($finlikes);?>;" id="likes"></div></div>
             <a  onclick="dislike()" id="dislikebtn"><img id="adislike" src="img/icons/dislike.png" alt = "dislike" /></a>      
            <p id= "likesnum"><?php echo $likes; ?></p>
            <p id= "dislikesnum"><?php echo $dislikes; ?></p> 

                  <script type="text/javascript">
                        var Liked = "<?php echo $liked;?>";
                        var Disliked = "<?php echo $disliked;?>";

                        var Art = "<?php echo $id;?>";
                        var User = "<?php echo $email;?>";
                        var olikes = "<?php echo $Olikes;?>";
                        var odislikes = "<?php echo $Odislikes;?>";
                        var state = "<?php echo $state1; ?>";
                        if(Liked == null){
                          Liked = false;

                        }
                        if(Disliked == null){
                          Disliked == false;
                        }
                        if(!Liked){
                           console.log("not liked!");
                        }
                        if(!Disliked){
                           console.log("not disliked!");
                        }
                        var loged = "<?php echo($log);?>";

                        window.onbeforeunload = function() {        
                            $.ajax({
                                  type: "GET",
                                  url: 'dealLikes.php?article='+Art+'&user='+User+'&state=1&likes='+likes+'&dislikes='+dislikes+'&Olikes='+olikes+'&Odislikes='+odislikes+'&prev='+state+'',
                                  success: function(data){
                                     console.log("Its done!");
                                  }
                              });
                        };

                        setInterval(function changetext(){

                             document.getElementById('likesnum').innerHTML = likes;
                             document.getElementById('dislikesnum').innerHTML = dislikes;
                                if(Liked){
                                   document.getElementById('alike').src = "img/icons/like1.png";
                                }else{
                                  document.getElementById('alike').src = "img/icons/like.png";
                                }
                                if(Disliked){
                                   document.getElementById('adislike').src = "img/icons/dislike1.png";
                                }else{
                                  document.getElementById('adislike').src = "img/icons/dislike.png";
                                }
                         },20);

                        function like(){

                                if(loged){
                                  if(Liked){
                                    likes-=1;
                                    Liked = false;
                                    // document.getElementById('alike').src = "img/icons/like.png";
                                  }else if(Disliked){
                                      dislikes-=1;
                                      Disliked = false;
                                      likes+=1;
                                      Liked = true;
                                    //  document.getElementById('alike').src = "img/icons/like1.png";
                                    //  document.getElementById('adislike').src = "img/icons/dislike.png";
                                  }else{
                                      likes+=1;
                                      Liked = true;
                                     // document.getElementById('alike').src = "img/icons/like1.png";
                                  }
                                }else{
                                   window.location = "login";
                                }
                        }

                        function dislike(){
                          if(loged){
                            if(Disliked){
                              dislikes-=1;
                              Disliked = false;
                              // document.getElementById('adislike').src = "img/icons/dislike.png";
                            }else if(Liked){
                              likes-=1;
                              Liked = false;
                              dislikes+=1;
                              Disliked = true;
                            //  document.getElementById('adislike').src = "img/icons/dislike1.png";
                               //document.getElementById('alike').src = "img/icons/like.png";
                            }else{
                              dislikes+=1;
                              Disliked = true;
                             // document.getElementById('adislike').src = "img/icons/dislike1.png";

                            }
                            }else{
                               window.location = "login";
                            }

                        }

                  </script>
               </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

What is wrong with the code that makes it not update the amount of likes on the first refresh but does update on the second refresh?

Comment: Because you're using `get` requests, which CAN be cached by the browser. Plus, you're vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). Plus... `select id  where id=select(max)`? That is incredibly convoluted when you could LITERALLY have `select max(id) from videos`.

Comment: You use $0dislikes in php and var dislikes = <?php echo $dislikes;?>; in js. Two different variables. The same is with $0likes and $likes. And $0likes holds the updated likes, so if you chnage it to $likes it should work (the same for dislikes)